# MySQL seems fine but Laravel doesn't like it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Consider this code:

```
$search = "John";

return User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%$search%')")
             ->take(20)
             ->toSql();
```

This generates the following SQL code:

```
select * from `users` 
where (CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%John%') 
limit 20
```

If I change the `toSql()` above to `get()` then Laravel returns the relevant records.

So far, so good.

Then, if I change the value of `$search` to `John%Anthony` and run the above code again, Laravel generates this SQL:

```
select * from `users` 
where (CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%John%Anthony%') 
limit 20
```

If I run this query directly in MySQL, it works fine and returns the relevant rows. However, Laravel (v5.2) doesn't seem to like it because When I change `toSql()` to `get()` I get this error:

```
UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 397:

The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Comment: Try changing it to: `whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%?%')", [$search])`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the error was caused by data in a `BLOB` field in the MySQL table. It wasn't appearing for the first recordset because their `BLOB` fields didn't include quotes. However, for the second recordset, the `BLOB` field had a double quote in one of the records and that was throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
User::hydrateRaw(select * from `users` 
where (CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%$search%') 
limit 20)
```